# How do I find all rows such that the string in a column is a substring of a given string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In other words, I want to do the reverse of `df.str.contains(somestring)`. I want something like `somestring.contained_in(df.column)` that still returns a series.

Say I have a string `abjk` and I have a dataframe

```
index    letter
0        a
1        b
2        c
...      ...
25       z
```

Then it should return rows 0, 1, 9, 10 as `True`. This feels like something that should exist, but I can't seem to find it. Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just do :

```py
[l in 'abjk' for l in df.letter]
```

If you want later to return the rows, you could just use numpy.where

```py
import numpy as np
 rows,  = np.where([l in 'abjk' for l in df.letter])
```